# Feature importance of the predicted value in random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I did my price prediction using **RandomForest** **Regressor** with **Sklearn** . I am able to get the feature importance using feature_importances_ function of Randomforest regressor. Now i want to know which features are affecting the individual results of the data that needs to be predicted.
I cannot share the data as it is confidential just think of it as a medical claim file with 8 columns which have correlation with the actual price.
Pardon me if this question sound noob i am new to machine learning world.
Please give me some guidance as i am stuck up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called **"model interpretation"**.

There is a famous trade-off between flexibility and interpretability. See [here](https://cyzne.wordpress.com/2015/05/28/flexibility-vs-interpretability-in-data-analysis/) for a short explanation.

Now, Random Forests are fairly flexible, hence are hard to interpret. Some people even claim that this is impossible.

Keeping in mind the above, there are some people who tried to do that. 
See [here](https://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/) for a way of doing this, and [here](https://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/) for a code example.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.